# Angular Material Select Optional Multiple Selects

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hello I'm trying to wrap the angular material select in a shared component. Everything is working like a charm except for only one thing, And that is the "multiple" property.

I'm trying to bind to a "@Input()" property "multiple", the code is as follows

dropdown.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'dropdown',
    templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class DropdownComponent {
    @Input() dropdownLabel: string;
    @Input() categorized: boolean = false;
    @Input() multiple: boolean = false;
    @Input() data: any[] = [];
}
```

dropdown.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{ dropdownLabel }}</mat-label>
    <mat-select multiple="multiple">
        <!-- If is categorized add groups -->
        <ng-container *ngIf="categorized">
            <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of data" [label]="group.name">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of group.children" [value]="item">{{ item.name }}</mat-option>
            </mat-optgroup>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- if is not categorized add elements without groups -->
        <ng-container *ngIf="!categorized">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of data" [value]="item">{{ item.name }}</mat-option>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I've tried in the html file when I type multiple="false" or "true", it works.

But when I bind it to the variable "multiple" in my js file that has a default value "false", it always activates the multiple selection behavior.

Any idea how to get around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you bind with the following [syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#one-time-string-initialization):

```
multiple="multiple"
```

the `multiple` property is bound to the string `"multiple"`. Since any non empty string is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), the `multiple` property is activated. Apparently, Angular Material interprets the string `"false"` as falsy; so that the following syntax turns off the `multiple` option of the select component:

```
multiple="false"
```

To make sure that Angular evaluates the expression `multiple` correctly, use the property binding syntax with the [brackets](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#remember-the-brackets):

```
[multiple]="multiple"
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcz6b6?file=app/select-multiple-example.html) for a demo.